# Internet Explorer driver is not working in Selenium Python bindings

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-9

I am using "Python 3.4.1" 32 bit on Windows 7 x86_64 system.

I am trying to automate a task which involves interacting with a website. And for that I am using "Selenium" with Python.

The following code works fine while opening "Firefox":

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

I want the script to work for Internet Explorer as well. I have IE 9, and I downloaded "IEDriverServer_Win32_2.44.0" for IE driver to work.
But, when I try to run the code:

```
driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe")
```

or

```
driver = webdriver.Ie()
```

it opens up the command prompt with the title of the command prompt window frame being "C:\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe" with a blinking cursor and then gives the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 46, in **init**
    self.iedriver.start()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\service.py", line 79, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the IEDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the IEDriver

I even added to "Path" variable the path to IEDriverServer.exe but it's still giving the error (The path is: C:\IEDriver)

What do I do to get IE running?

Thanks!

Comment: is IEdriverServer installed?

Comment: I downloaded the "IEDriverServer_Win32_2.44.0.zip" and placed the "IEDriverServer.exe" in "C:\IEDriver\"

Comment: is your path correct? `driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe")`

Comment: why do you have 2 backwards slash after IEDriver?

Comment: Yes, it is. I created a new folder "C:\IEDriver" and placed the exe file "IEDriverServer.exe" within the folder.

Comment: but why do you have 2 backwards slashes in your path?

Comment: Even doing driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\IEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe") opens up the command prompt and does nothing.

Comment: i would try Python 2 otherwise i m out of ideas

Comment: You are saying that in Python 3.4.1, this won't work? Should I try Python 2.7.8? But, why won't it work in Python 3.X ?

Comment: Smushi, I installed Python 2.7.8 but the problem persists. Any leads?

Comment: nope out of ideas man.